# Two queues: the script doesn't exit

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, queue

I wrote a script that uses 2 queues and 3 types of worker: producer, consumer (CPU-bound task), writer (I need to write the results sequentially).

This is the simplified version of my code:

```
from queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

def compute_single_score(data):
    #do lots of calculations
    return 0.0

def producer(out_q, data_to_compute):
    while stuff:
        data = data_to_compute.popitem()
        out_q.put(data)
    out_q.put(_sentinel)

def consumer(in_q, out_q):
    while True:
        data = in_q.get()
        if data is _sentinel:
            in_q.put(_sentinel)
            break
        out_q.put([data[0], compute_single_score(*data)])
        in_q.task_done()

def writer(in_q):
    while True:
        data = in_q.get()
        if data is _sentinel:
            in_q.put(_sentinel)
            break
        in_q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _sentinel = object()
    jobs_queue = Queue()
    scores_queue = Queue()

    t1 = Thread(target=producer, args=(jobs_queue, data_to_compute,))
    t2 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,))
    t3 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,))
    t4 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,))
    t5 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,))
    t6 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,))
    t7 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,))
    t8 = Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,))
    t9 = Thread(target=writer, args=(scores_queue,))

    t1.start(); t2.start(); t3.start(); t4.start(); t5.start(); t6.start(); t7.start(); t8.start(); t9.start()

    jobs_queue.join()
    scores_queue.join()
    print('File written')
```

It immediately prints out 'File written', instead waiting for the queues to be empty. Consequently the script doesn't exit although all the calculations are performed. Two threads seem to remain active.

Thanks a lot for your support.

Answer (score 1):

It does wait for queues to be empty. But since putting things in queue happens in threads then it reaches `.join()` line faster then `.put()` happens. So when it does reach `.join()` queues are empty.

Now I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve simply because a producer has a `while stuff` loop. I assume that you want to continue processing until this condition is true. In particular you have to wait until `t1` thread quits, i.e.

```
t1.start(); t2.start(); t3.start(); t4.start(); t5.start(); t6.start(); t7.start(); t8.start(); t9.start()

t1.join() # <-- this is important
jobs_queue.join()
scores_queue.join()
print('File written')
```

Otherwise you won't be able to synchronize it.

*Side note 1*: due to GIL there is no point in creating CPU bound threads. If your threads are not doing any IO (and they don't) then it will perform better when single-threaded. Well at least multiple `consumer` threads are pointless.

*Side note 2*: Do not use commas. It's not pythonic. Instead do this:

```
threads = []
threads.append(Thread(target=producer, args=(jobs_queue, data_to_compute,)))
threads.append(Thread(target=writer, args=(scores_queue,)))
for i in range(10):
    threads.append(Thread(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,)))

for t in threads:
    t.start()

threads[0].join()
```

*Side note 3*: You should handle case when queues are empty. `data = in_q.get()` will block forever meaning that your script won't quit (unless threads are marked as `daemon`). You should do for example:

```
try:
    data = in_q.get(timeout=1)
except queue.Empty:
    # handle empty queue here, perhaps quit if t1 is not alive
    # otherwise just continue the loop

    if not t1.is_alive(): # <-- you have to pass t1 to the thread
        break
    else:
        continue
```

and then join all threads at the end (see *side note 2*) of the main thread:

```
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print('File written')
```

And now you don't even have to join queues.

Comment: What do you suggest to solve the (Side note 1)? Processes? In this case how could I modify the script? Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @michele If you are doing some cpu heavy job then I suggest not using Python in the first place. You could play with C plugins but having a separate C/C++ service is probably better. If you really have to stick with Python then have a look at multiprocessing module. Spawning more processes is the only way of taking advantage of multiple cores in Python.

Comment: It still doesn't exit. :(

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I used in the end (according to the requirements illustrated before):

```
from multiprocessing import JoinableQueue
from multiprocessing import Process

def compute_single_score(data):
    #do lots of calculations
    return 0.0

def producer(out_q, data_to_compute):
    while stuff:
        data = data_to_compute.popitem()
        out_q.put(data)

def consumer(in_q, out_q):
    while True:
        try:
            data = in_q.get(timeout=5)
        except:
            break
        out_q.put([data[0], compute_single_score(*data)])
        in_q.task_done()

def writer(in_q):
    while True:
        try:
            data = in_q.get(timeout=5)
        except:
            break
        #write
        in_q.task_done()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs_queue = JoinableQueue()
    scores_queue = JoinableQueue()

    processes = []
    processes.append(Process(target=producer, args=(jobs_queue, data_to_compute,)))
    processes.append(Process(target=writer, args=(scores_queue,)))
    for i in range(10):
        processes.append(Process(target=consumer, args=(jobs_queue,scores_queue,)))

    for p in processes:
        p.start()

    processes[1].join()
    scores_queue.join()

    print('File written')
```

I hope it will be of help for somebody else.